# How to get rid of the border lines at the edge of my shaded error bars/areas in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The graph is good but it would look a lot more professional if there was not a hard line at the edge of the error bars, which are defined with ribbons with ggplot2.

[image: the graph in question]

If I change the geom_line it changes the main line, which I want to stay as it is.  Can anyone help a rookie out?

[image: the code in question for the graph]

Comment: Add `linetype = 0` to `geom_ribbon`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to move the mapping to the colour aesthetic to the geom_line

`geom_line(aes(colour = Measure), linetype = 'solid', size = 1.2)`